# In Scala, what does "view" do?

Tags: scala

Specifically I'm looking at Problem 1 here

http://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/

The code as listed is as follows

```
val r = (1 until 1000).view.filter(n => n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0).sum
```

I can follow everything except for "view".  In fact if I take out view the code still compiles and produces exactly the same answer.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

View produces a lazy collection, so that calls to e.g. `filter` do not evaluate every element of the collection. Elements are only evaluated once they are explicitly accessed. Now `sum` does access all elements, but with `view` the call to `filter` doesn't create a full Vector. (See comment by Steve)

A good example of the use of view would be:

```
scala> (1 to 1000000000).filter(_ % 2 == 0).take(10).toList
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Here Scala tries to create a collection with `1000000000` elements to then access the first 10. But with view:

```
scala> (1 to 1000000000).view.filter(_ % 2 == 0).take(10).toList
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
```

Comment: Nitpick: the statement "since sum accesses all elements, there is no point in using view here" isn't correct, because `filter` will try to create a full `Vector` before calling `sum` on it. Try replacing 1000 with 1000000000 in the original example and if you leave the `view` off you'll see the same memory problems you demonstrate above.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know much about Scala, but perhaps [this page](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) might help...

> There are two principal ways to implement transformers. One is strict, that is a new collection with all its elements is constructed as a result of the transformer. The other is non-strict or lazy, that is one constructs only a proxy for the result collection, and its elements get constructed only as one demands them.
>
> A **view** is a special kind of collection that represents some base collection, but implements all transformers lazily.

So it sounds as if the code will still work without `view`, but might in theory be doing some extra work constructing all the elements of your collection in *strict* rather than *lazy* fashion.

Answer (score 9):

The following answer is taken from the [Views section in the Hands-on Scala book](https://www.handsonscala.com/chapter-4-scala-collections.html#section-4-1-8-views).

When you chain multiple transformations on a collection, we are creating many intermediate collections
that are immediately thrown away. For example, in the following code:

```scala
@ val myArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
@ val myNewArray = myArray.map(x => x + 1).filter(x => x % 2 == 0).slice(1, 3)

myNewArray: Array[Int] = Array(4, 6)
```

The chain of `.map` `.filter` `.slice` operations ends up traversing the collection three times, creating three
new collections, but only the last collection ends up being stored in `myNewArray` and the others are
discarded.

```
myArray
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

map(x => x + 1)
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
2,4,6,8,10

slice(1, 3)
myNewArray
4,6
```

This creation and traversal of intermediate collections is wasteful. In cases where you have long chains of
collection transformations that are becoming a performance bottleneck, you can use the `.view` method
together with `.to` to **fuse** the operations together:

```scala
@ val myNewArray = myArray.view.map(_ + 1).filter(_ % 2 == 0).slice(1, 3).to(Array)
myNewArray: Array[Int] = Array(4, 6)
```

Using `.view` before the `map/filter/slice` transformation operations defers the actual traversal and
creation of a new collection until later, when we call `.to` to convert it back into a concrete collection type:

```
myArray
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

view map filter slice to

myNewArray
4,6
```

This allows us to perform this chain of `map/filter/slice` transformations with only a single traversal, and
only creating a single output collection. This reduces the amount of unnecessary processing and memory
allocations.