# Combination of map and filter nulls out in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to express the following code in such a way that the map and null skipping is expressed in one call?

```
list.map(_.accept(this, arg).asInstanceOf[T]).filter(_ != null)
```

Comment: I guess that `_.accept(this, arg)` can return `null`. In this case slightly more idiomatic (although still with two calls): `list.map(i => Option(i.accept(this, arg).asInstanceOf[T])).flatten`

Comment: Please someone correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `collect` the combination of `map` and `filter`? Or was it the other way around? Or am I just wrong? ;)

Comment: @agilesteel, yes, collect might work. Could you contribute a code snippet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
list flatMap { i => Option(i.accept(this, arg).asInstanceOf[T]) }
```

or alternatively, if you like, (though this will be converted more or less to your original expression)

```
for {
  item <- list
  itemConverted = item.accept(this, arg).asInstanceOf[T]
  itemNonNull = itemConverted if itemConverted != 0
} yield itemNonNull
```

Using `collect` would be possible but it would likely call `accept` twice on most arguments because of the `isDefinedAt` test of the partial function:

```
list collect {
  case i if i.accept(this, arg).asInstanceOf[T] != null => i.accept(this, arg).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

One would need to use some memoising (or smart extractors) to avoid this.

Answer (score 8):

If you are concerned about performance, you can add `.view`

```
list.view.map(_.accept(this, arg).asInstanceOf[T]).filter(_ != null)
```

`view` causes the traversal to become lazy, thus the `map` and `filter` will be performed in one pass over the list rather than two separate passes.

If you are concerned about reusing this pattern, you can define your own helper function:

```
def mapNN[A,B](list: List[A])(f: A => B) = {
  list.view.map(f(_)).filter(_ != null)
}

mapNN(list)(_.accept(this, arg).asInstanceOf[T])
```

Testing...

```
> mapNN(List(1,2,3))(x => if (x%2==0) x else null).toList
res7: List[Any] = List(2)
```

Comment: Can you explain more on this part _thus the map and filter will be performed in one pass over the list rather than two separate passes_ ? How can it only need one pass to apply 2 transformations?

Comment: @MinhThai Here's a decent explanation of `view`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6799739/208257
Basically, it makes transformations lazy. It delays even doing a single pass, right up until you call `toList`, at which point it does a single pass, applying each transformation incrementally as it goes.