# Scala collection transformation performance: single looping vs. multiple looping

Tags: performance, scala, collections, iteration, scala-collections

When there is a collection and you must perform two or more operations on all of its elements, what is faster?:

```
val f1: String => String  = _.reverse
val f2: String => String  = _.toUpperCase
val elements: Seq[String] = List("a", "b", "c")
```

1. iterate multiple times and perform one operation on one loop

   `val result = elements.map(f1).map(f2)`

   This approach does have the advantage, that the result after application of the first function could be reused.
2. iterate one time and perform all operation on each element together

   `val result = elements.map(element => f2(f1(element)))`

   or

   `val result = elements.map(element => f1.compose(f2)`

Is there any difference in performance between these two approaches? And if yes, which is faster?

Comment: FYI: your second expression could be made more compact with `elements.map(f1.compose(f2))`.

Comment: Thx, for the hint. I will add it.

Comment: `f1 andThen f2` is different from `f1 compose f2`.

Comment: I will have a look on that later and will edit the question if necessary.

Comment: @som-snytt : my bad, it should indeed be `f2 compose f1`. Fortunately, in this case they're equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the thing, transformation of a collection is more or less of runtime O(N) , * runtime cost of all the functions applied. So I doubt the 2nd set of choices you present above would make even the slightest difference in runtime. The first option you list, is a different story. New collection creation can be avoided, because that could result in overhead. That's where "view" collections come in (see this good example I spotted)

[In Scala, what does "view" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799648/in-scala-what-does-view-do)

If you had the apply several mapping operations you might do this:

```
val result = elements.view.map(f1).map(f2).force
```

(force at the end, causes all functions to evaluate)
The 2nd set of examples above would maybe be a tiny bit faster, but the "view" option could make your code more readable if you had a lot of these or complex anonymous functions used in the mapping.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer, otherwise I would not write pretty much the same thing :)

Comment: oh hey it's all good! - glad to see confirmation of my thoughts anyhow, I don't use view often. But thanks for saying, really the more participation around scala on stackoverflow the better! =) @
A I fgfgf

Comment: A note from a nice article on Scala performance (http://www.sumologic.com/blog/technology/3-tips-for-writing-performant-scala): "However, for smaller values of n, the strict version will run faster. Lazy evaluation requires the creation of an additional closure. If creating the closures takes longer than creating intermediate collections, the lazy version will run slower. Profile and understand your bottlenecks before optimizing!"

Comment: @user573215 That's a really good point to mention.. any tips on how to profile a scala application? I work out of Intellij but can only work from my understanding, I've never tried to use a compiler tool to do so

Comment: I don't know if there are any Scala specific tools or techniques, you must research that on the web. Of course all the available Java tools will be an option. JConsole and JVisualVM already come with the JDK. A profiler is included in JVisualVM. Probably this question is answered best via MicroBenchmarking (MB). Be aware that MB is a very tricky task, but there are APIs / libraries available to perform MB. There is plenty material available explaining the difficulties of MB. I am working on answering this question via MB and will update if I can deliver some results.

Answer (score 1):

Composing functions to produce a single pass transformation will probably gain you some performance, but will quickly become unreadable. Consider using views as an alernative. While this will create intermediate collections:

```
val result = elements.map(f1).map(f2)
```

This will perform lazy evaluation and will perform functional composition the same way you do:

```
val result = elements.view.map(f1).map(f2)
```

Notice that result type will be `SeqView` so you might want to convert it to list later with `toList`.

Comment: 1.) I assume, that with using `view`, the functional composition of closures will be performed by the implementation of `view` under the hood. 2.) Is there a difference in performance between using `force` and `toList`? Or other advantages / disadvantages?