# Optimization of consecutive map/filter/fold calls

Tags: optimization, functional-programming, language-agnostic, higher-order-functions

Let's say I have a big list on which I'd like to execute multiple map, filter and fold/reduce calls. For clarity and expressiveness this should be done with small lambda functions passed to map/filter/fold. However, as far as I know, these are actually traversing the list every time, calling the lambda on it (might be inline though) and generating a new list. If this is the case, I could just code a for-each loop and merge all the lambdas into its body.

I measured execution time of a simple map/filter/reduce algorithm and the corresponding imperative for-each loop in Python and the latter was more than two times faster, just as I expected, but I know Python is not the best language in this regard.

My questions are: Is it possible for a compiler to figure out these and somehow merge them into a single loop? Are there any compilers that do this? I'm interested in mainly functional languages (Haskell, Erlang/Elixir, Scala), but would be good to hear about others as well (Rust's implementation, LINQ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, such optimizations have been considered many times.

One term or method used is ["fusion"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/578063/1346276) (also known as stream or [map fusion](http://www.randomhacks.net/2007/02/10/map-fusion-and-haskell-performance/)), which has the goal of intelligently inlining iterated trasformations, in patterns like `map f . map g = map (f . g)`. This mostly has to be done with the help of a compiler, but can work on "normal" implementations of these functions (if they are done somewhat intelligently).

Another approach is to perform this kind of inlining manually by accumulating all intermediate closures, and only apply the combinded transformation when the values are actually needed (this is closely related to lazy evaluation, a thing which will in some languages, like Haskell, be done automatically). Such things can be found in Scala's [views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6799648/1346276) and `Stream`s, or Clojure's [transducers](http://clojure.org/reference/transducers) (which work in a more complicated way, though). The problem with these lazy things is that they tend to run into space problems more easily (I've heard).

Iterators in Python (and C#'s `IEnumerable`/LINQ stuff, and Java's new `Stream`s) principle work via the latter principle, involving a language-provided iteration support (involving some internal state). Which is why `xs = map(print, range(10))` will not print anything immediately, and can only be traversed once; at every step of the iteration, the nested iterators will ask each other for the next value, transform it, and update their state. (And probably your measured difference is due more to this involved machinery than to repeated iteration.)