# How to write filter with limit on Scala?

Tags: scala, filter, functional-programming

Let I have big array of some structure (in example below Int is for simplicity) and want to filter this array and take first n elements. How can I do it?

Example:

> ```
> val outerVar = 22
>
> def filterFunction(a: Int): Boolean = {
>   if (true/* some condition into this */) return false
>   if (a > 12) return true
>   if (a > 750) return false
>   if (a == 42) return true
>   if (a == outerVar) return true
>   // etc conditions that can use context of outer space
>   false
> }
>
> val n = 42
> val bigArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> val result = bigArray.filter(element => {
>   filterFunction(element)
> })
> //.limit(n) (something like)
> // how to stop filling result after it will contain n elements?
> ```

Comment: `result.take(n)` ?

Comment: first of all you need to get rid of return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Scala, what does "view" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799648/in-scala-what-does-view-do)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your predicate `filterFunction` is not going to do its work, since it always returns `false`.

Let's consider a toy example where we have an `Array[Int]` and we need to apply `filter` on it with predicate `filterFunction` so that the evaluation stops once `n` elements have been fetched:

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val array = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
val filterFunction = (a: Int) => a > 5
val getLazy = (n: Int) => array.view.filter(filterFunction).take(n).toArray

getLazy(2)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

array: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
filterFunction: Int => Boolean = <function1>
getLazy: Int => Array[Int] = <function1>
res0: Array[Int] = Array(6, 7)
```

`array.view.filter(filterFunction).take(n)` becomes lazy expression (which is not evaluated right away) and `toArray` in fact runs the calculations.