# Equivalent of Scala View in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

In Scala, `view` allows preventing creating an entirely new collection.
e.g. [In Scala, what does "view" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799648/in-scala-what-does-view-do)

Is there something similar in JavaScript?
My use case:

```
x = inputValue.split(",").map(x => x.trim()).filter(f1).map(f2)
```

As you can see in the above code, 2 intermediate collections would be created. Is there some way in JavaScript to avoid creating the above intermediate collections?

Comment: I have no idea, but I really want to learn that!!! Very good question.

Comment: You're basically asking about transducers? Like https://github.com/cognitect-labs/transducers-js or RamdaJS (and many others)? As described in https://medium.com/@roman01la/understanding-transducers-in-javascript-3500d3bd9624? (The web is your friend. I searched for "javascript fp don't create intermediate collections".)

Comment: @DaveNewton yes... i already visited above link... but is it possible to achieve something useful without above library.

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati Sure, implement it the way they do--the source is trivially available for study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala is a strict language similarily to Javascript. That means that if you create a list and use *map*, then Scala would eagerly create a new list:

```
//it creates List(2,3,4) and List(4,6,8) already when map is called
List(1,2,3).map(_ + 1).map(_ *2)
```

You can make Scala collections lazy though by calling *view*:

```
val l = List(1,2,3).view.map(_ + 1).map(_ * 2) //nothing happens yet
l.take(2) //only 1 and 2 get processed
```

Unfortunately, there is no built-in function in Javascript to make array behave lazily, but there is a library [Lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/), which works similarly to Scala view:

```
Lazy([1,2,3]).map(x => x + 1).map(x => x * 2).take(2).toArray()
```

And according to docs:

> What's important here is that no iteration takes place until you call each, and **no intermediate arrays are created**.

Comment: JavaScript has iterators.

Comment: Iterators don't support *map*, *reduce*, *filter,* etc. It's not the same as the lazy collection.

Comment: I know, the API is shamefully impoverished, but my point is that they can be used to implement such operations.