# Lazily map, filter, reduce, etc. in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

`Array#map`, `Array#filter` create a new array and hence effectively iterating over the array (or creating new array).

Whereas in rust, python, java, c#, etc. such expression chain will iterate only once.

In most cases this is irrelevant and we do not have to care about that. However in some cases the performance hit could be a deal breaker to leverage the function api of the `Array` class.

How do you mitigate this? So you have any preference on a library enabling lazy evaluation for functional expression?

Comment: Write it out as a loop, or use [iterator methods](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers).

Comment: What if `reduce` is chained further with a `map`? How can that in general work without first performing the whole iteration needed to perform the reduction?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042520/equivalent-of-scala-view-in-javascript/57043367

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-list does exactly this. `npm i stream-list`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want it to iterate more than once. You can use a loop

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let result = 0;
for(const number of numbers) {
  const square = number * number
  if(square % 2) {
    result += square
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

Or reduce

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const result = numbers.reduce((acc, number) => {
  const square = number * number
  if(square % 2) {
    return acc + square
  }
  return acc
}, 0)
console.log(result)
```

Array methods aren't functional so the whole premise is flawed. The fact that they exist on the array object means they aren't open composition the way pure functions are. You can get closer though

```js
const square = (n) => n * n
const oddNumberOrZero = (n) => n % 2 ? n : 0
const add = (a, b) => a + b
const addOddSquare = (a, b) => add(a, oddNumberOrZero(square(b)))
const reduce = (arr, fn, acc) => arr.reduce(fn,acc)
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

const result = reduce(numbers, addOddSquare, 0)

console.log(result)
```

You also seem to be conflating fluent interfaces with functional programming.

Comment: Well array methods aren't strictly functional. They are just methods on the Array prototype which is by all measures object oriented.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is processing the array as a stream. You can do that with [highland](https://caolan.github.io/highland/):

```
import _ from "highland";
_([1, 2, 3, 4])
    .filter(v => v % 2 === 0)
    .map(v => v * 2)
    .toArray((result: number[]) => {
        // result is the new array
    });
```

Relevant part from the [docs](https://caolan.github.io/highland/#_(source)):

> Arrays - Streams created from Arrays will emit each value of the Array (...)

Answer (score 0):

You can install stream-list lib from npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-list

```
let myNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 let mylist = new List(myNumbers);
 myList
  .filter((num) => num % 2 == 0)  //only pair
  .map((num) => num * num)  // square
  .map((num) => num/2) // half
  .toList(); // myNumbers was just itered once
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following code lines.
In the code, in which v * v is divided 2 means that v is divided.

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const res = numbers.reduce((sum, v)=> sum + (v % 2? v * v: 0), 0);
console.log(res)
```